# Problema para gravar radioButton no db com Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, radiobutton

Tenho um formulário onde os dados nele colocado é gravado no `db` por um `jQuery`, mas nos `radiobutton` não consigo gravar o item que seleciono.
Abaixo uma parte do meu formulário. No radiobutton `Sexo_Segurado` que tenho o problema.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CPF_Segurado, htmlAttributes: new { 
            @class = "Myclass" 
        })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CPF_Segurado, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
            @id = "CPF_Segurado", 
            @type = "text", 
            @placeholder = "Ex: 142.035.046-43", 
            @class = "form-control" 
        } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CPF_Segurado, "", new { 
            @class = "text-danger" 
        })

    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data_Nasc_Segurado, htmlAttributes: new { 
            @class = "Myclass" 
        })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data_Nasc_Segurado, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
            @type = "date", 
            @placeholder = "01/01/2019", 
            @class = "form-control" 
        } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data_Nasc_Segurado, "", new { 
            @class = "text-danger" 
        })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sexo_Segurado, htmlAttributes: new { 
            @class = "Myclass"
         })
        <br />

        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Sexo_Segurado,"Masculino", new {  
            name = "Masculino", 
            @value = "Masculino", 
            @id = "Sexo_Segurado",  
            @class = "with-gap" 
        })
        <label for="Masculino">Masculino</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Sexo_Segurado, "Feminino", new {  
            name = "Feminino", 
            @value = "Feminino", 
            @id = "Sexo_Segurado", 
            @checked = "checked", 
            @class = "with-gap" 
        })
        <label for="Feminino">Feminino</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Abaixo segue meu Jquery que utilizo para salvar os dados do formulário:

```
function SalvarCliente() {
debugger;
//Segurado
var cpf_segurado = $("#CPF_Segurado").val();
var data_nasc_segurado = $("#Data_Nasc_Segurado").val();
var sexo_segurado = $("#Sexo_Segurado").val();
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
var tokenadr = $('form[action="/Cliente/Create"]inputname="__RequestVerification"]').val();

var headers = {};
var headersadr = {};
headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;
headersadr['__RequestVerificationToken'] = tokenadr;

var url = "/Cliente/Create";
$.ajax({
    url: url
    , type: "POST"
    , datatype: "json"
    , headers: headersadr
    , data: {
        Id: 0,
        CPF_Segurado: cpf_segurado,
        Data_Nasc_Segurado: data_nasc_segurado,
        Sexo_Segurado: sexo_segurado,
        __RequestVerificationToken: token
     }
    , success: function (data) {
        if (data.Resultado > 0) {

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Galera acho que resolvi. nessa parte do Jquery:

```
var sexo_segurado = $("#Sexo_Segurado").val();
```

é só consertar para:

```
var sexo_segurado = $("#Sexo_Segurado:checked").val();
```

que funciona.

Comment: Tenta assim: $("#Sexo_Segurado").attr('checked')

Answer (score 0):

Agora apareceu outro problema. Tenho esse Jquery que controla meus fieldtooltip:

```
!function (e) {e('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    for (var t = e("input[name='" + e(this).attr("name") + "']"),
        n = 0; n < t.length; n++)e(t[n]).parents(".radio").removeClass("erro"),
            e(e(this).parents("div").get(1)).children(".msg-erro").html(""),
            e(e(this).parents("p").get(1)).children(".msg-erro").html("")
    }),
    e('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
    e(this).focus(function () {
        e(this).parent().addClass("radioFocus")
    }),
        e(this).blur(function () {
        e(this).parent().removeClass("radioFocus")
    })
    }),e("#mesma-pessoa-fieldtooltip").length > 0 && (e("#Confirm_Proprietario_1").change(function () {
        e(this).is(":checked") && e("#mesma-pessoa-fieldtooltip").hide()
    }),     

        e("#Confirm_Proprietario_0").change(function () {
        e(this).is(":checked") && e("#mesma-pessoa-fieldtooltip").show()
        }),
        e("#Confirm_Proprietario_1").trigger("change"),
        e("#Confirm_Proprietario_0").trigger("change")),}(jQuery);
```

Oberservem que cada radiobutton eu utilizo um id, mas no Jquery que uso pra gravar no db ele só grava se tiver com mesmo id os radiobutton. Como eu poderia mudar o script acima de modo que o fieldtooltip funcione para os radiobutton com mesmo id?